# How to copy 19 million rows having text data type columns in faster way to another table in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, batch-file, ssis, bulkinsert

I need to perform a task in which we have a table who has 19 columns with text data type. I want to delete these columns from this source table and move those columns to a new table with data type as varchar(max). The source table has currently 30k rows (with text data type data). This will increase eventually as client will use the database for record storage. For transferring this  old data i tried to use "insert into..select.." query but it is taking around 25-30 mins to transfer these much rows(30k). Same is the case with "Select from..insert.." query. I have also tried creating data flow task of SSIS for transferring with OLE DB  as source and destination as well. But still it's taking same amount of time. I'm really confused as all posts over internet suggests that SSIS is fastest way for data transfer. Can you please suggests me better way to improve performance of data transfer using any technique?

Thanks

Comment: If 30 min for 19 mio rows is reasonable performance depends on your system. What's wrong with it if this is a one-time task? If you need to constantly do this, I suspect you'll have to reconsider your design.

Comment: @Filburt It is one-time task and it's taking 30 mins for 30k rows only.It will grow eventually after say 3-4 months when we do this migration.We have clients on SaaS and for this much time we may need to keep system down. That's why i'm a thinking a better way to do this.

Comment: Have you any trigges on the destination table ?, that would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS probably isn't faster if the source and the destination are in the same database and the SSIS process is on the same box.

One approach might be to figure out where you are spending the time and optimise that. If you set Management Studio to "discard results after execution" and run just the `select` part of your query, how long does that take? If this is a substantial part of the 25-30 minutes then work on optimising that.

If the `select` statement turns out to be really fast, then all the time is being spent on the insert and you need to look at improving that part of the process instead. There are a couple of things you can try here before you go hardware shopping; are there any indexes or constraints (or triggers!) on the target table that you can drop for the duration of the insert and put back again at the end? Can you put the database in simple mode?

Comment: i've already put database in simple mode and there are not constraints and indexes on destination table. Regarding select query,it is taking too much time in selecting only 10k rows. I guess this is due to huge data in each column of source table (each column is of type text). What would you suggests for this?

Comment: Here is the execution plan of select query for 10000 rows

Comment: Its taking 100% time for scanning table and total time spawn is around 8 mins

Comment: Are you meeting the other criteria for minimally logged insert (notably TABLOCK hint for the target table)?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Yes i am using TABLOCK on target table. Also i've not created any index (clustered/non clustered) as some it would take more time for bulk insert in this case. The only thing from the link you have provided is my target table is empty and i am trying to insert data in a batch of 5000 rows. This would create minimal logging for first batch insert? Please see my query below;

Comment: DECLARE BS INT = 5000 WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN INSERTINTO [dbo].[Target]WITH(TABLOCK)( col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17,col18,col19)SELECT TOP(BS)[Source].col1,[Source].col2,[Source].col3,[Source].col5,[Source].col6,[Source].col7,[Source].col8,[Source].col9,[Source].col10,[Source].col11,[Source].col12,[Source].col13,[Source].col14,[Source].col15,[Source].col16,[Source].col17,[Source].col18,[Source].col19 FROM [dbo].[Source] WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[Target]  WHERE dbo.[Target].col1 = Source].col1) IF @@ROWCOUNT < BS BREAK END

Comment: This is the killer here ...
_WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[Target] WHERE dbo.[Target].col1 = Source].col1)_
...
especially as there are no indexes on the target. Try to define the batches on the source, e.g. with 
_WHERE PK_col BETWEEN x and y_